# Create data set from multiple text fileד

Tags: r

I am trying to read text files, but get an error

```
read.table(file = "body_acc_x_train", header = TRUE, sep = "")

Error:
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Inertial Signals': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you try with the full path of the file (something like `/home/user/.../body_acc_x_train`), and confirdm it doesn't have an extension. If this works check which folder R thinks it is in? The  `getwd()` command gives this info.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to [ask]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setwd` for a working directory in your environment and set the parameters according to your data correctly e.g.:

```
# --- set working directory ----
setwd("D:/Data/R-Studio/develop/data-develop/maps")

gauge.data <- read.table("gauge-WSP.txt", header=TRUE, 
                         sep="\t", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE,
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
gauge.data
```

The gauge data here are separated with tabs and have some `NA`'s as an example.

If you meant with your question *"import some files simultaneously rather than having to import them all individually"* have alook at [How to import multiple .csv files at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once).

This assumes that you have your files in a single directory - the current working directory - (see above) and that all of them have an extension.